# Get all the members in a distribution group from a SMTP server in dot net

Tags: .net, email, c#-4.0, smtpclient

Is it possible to get all members / users list present in a distribution group for given SMTP server?

For e.g I have a distribution group called Group@company.com. Is it possible to get all the members / users present in the Group@company.com using the SMTP client?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it just by using SMTP client because all SMTP protocol intended for - is just sending mail.

Briefly (and very simplified), all SMTP server allows client to do - is just connect and post some data: message headers (including from, to and so on) and message body.

If message recipient is not found by SMTP server - it may (and may not - it depends on server settings) report error. So all you can do - is just detect if some email recipient exists on server, but this not guaranteed - see above about server settings.

Distribution group - is truly internal to server and doesn't exposes to public. All you can do via SMTP - is just send message to this group.